# Asymptotes of a rational function

Tags: calculus

We have a function $$f(x) =\dfrac{2x^4+4x^3+3x^2+4x-4}{x^3-x^2-6x}$$

How would I systematically go about finding the asymptotes of this function? I know how to find the asymptotes of for example log functions or functions with a square root in it, but I don't really know how to find them for this function.

Comment: Rational functions of polynomials can have vertical asymptotes [see, for instance, http://www.purplemath.com/modules/asymtote.htm ] , horizontal asymptotes [ http://www.purplemath.com/modules/asymtote2.htm ] , or oblique/slant  asymptotes [ http://www.purplemath.com/modules/asymtote3.htm ] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be simplified by dividing the numerator and denominator by $(x+2)$:

$$
\dfrac{2x^3+3x-2}{x^2-3x} \\
$$

- [Vertical asymptotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Vertical_asymptotes) occur where $y$ tends to infinity, which happens at the roots of the denominator:
  $$
  x^2 - 3x = x (x - 3) = 0 \\
  $$
  There are two roots so the vertical asymptotes are $x = 0$ and $x = 3$.
- [Horizontal asymptotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Horizontal_asymptotes) occur where $x$ tends to infinity, which becomes clear by dividing the numerator and the denominator by the highest power of $x$:
  $$
  \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2x^3+3x-2}{x^2-3x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2+3/x^2-2/x^3}{1/x-3/x^2} = \infty \\
  $$
  There is no limit so there are no horizontal asymptotes.
- [Oblique asymptotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Oblique_asymptotes) occur where the graph approaches the line $(mx+b)$, which becomes clear by dividing the numerator and denominator:
  $$
  \dfrac{2x^3+3x-2}{x^2-3x} = 2x + 6 \text{ remains } 21x - 2 \\
  $$
  There is a whole part so the oblique asymptote is $y = 2x + 6$.

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean division of the numerator by the denominator: if 
$$N(x)=(ax+b)D(x)+R(x)\quad \deg R(x)<\deg D(x),$$
the $y=ax+b$ is the equation of the asymptote.

Naturally there is an asymptote only if  $\deg D(x)\le \deg N(x)\le\deg D(x)+1$.